# Know when dictation has ended in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, dictation

I'd like to know when dictation has end (ideally also when it started).

My `UIViewController` which includes the `UITextView` conforms to the `UITextInputDelegate` protocol.

To make it work I had to subscribe to the `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "changeInputMode:", name: UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

and add the delegate there (it didn't work simply adding it to the viewDidLoad())

```
func changeInputMode(sender : NSNotification) {
    textView.inputDelegate = self
}
```

Starting and stopping dictation the UITextInput now correctly calls the required delegate methods:

```
func selectionWillChange(textInput: UITextInput){    }
func selectionDidChange(textInput: UITextInput){    }
func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput){    }
func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput){    }
```

However what doesn't get called is

```
func dictationRecordingDidEnd() {
    println("UITextInput Dictation ended")
}
```

Why? How can I get notified/call a method on dictation having ended?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, here's what worked for me not using the `UITextInput` protocol but the `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification` instead.

```
func changeInputMode(sender : NSNotification) {
    var primaryLanguage = textView.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage

    if primaryLanguage != nil {
        var activeLocale:NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: primaryLanguage!)
        if primaryLanguage == "dictation" {
            // dictation started
        } else {
            // dictation ended
        }
    }
}
```